# How to search inside multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-indexing

## Detailed

Imagine that we have tables which looks like that:

[image]

As you see, `questions` is connected with 4 tables via Foreign key.

Using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/index) with [server-side processing](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) (I modified given php code to work with multiple tables) for clientside.

## Question

What I want to do is following: when user searches for something, clientside sends keywords via ajax into serverside. The piece of code which handles search on official website ([link to page](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)) looks like that:

```
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```

I want to modify this part to handle multiple table processing.

For ex: If user entered some section's name (name located in `sections` table, `section` column), how can I find questions (from `questions` table) related with this section? Is that possible with one and only query?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You want to take a look at SQL `join` statements

Comment: For the time being: get rid of the subjects table. (or reference it via N<>M tables)

Comment: @wildplasser I can't get rid off. It's very good structure. The only problem occured here. Actually the problem, can be resolved with huge amount of code. But I'm looking for some fresh idea. BTW, WHat do you mean by `reference it via N<>M tables` ?

Comment: @SaladinAkara I know what is `JOIN`. lol:)) Can't figure out, how to implement this into function

Comment: Well, in the current model a {question,chapter,paragraph,section} each can have only one subject. My guess is that subjects are more like tags, and that {....} should be allowed to have more than one subject.

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu A `join` goes before the where clause, so it wouldn't go into your currently posted code. Please include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use LIKE operator for this at all, especially if these tables can grow beyond a few hundred rows. LIKE with a wildcard in front (e.g. `LIKE '%key'` or `LIKE '%key%'`) cannot use any indexes to optimize the searches, which means these queries may become quite slow with only thousands of rows.

Ideally, you should build a denormalized structure that contains any text-searchable information in a single row and then throw it into a full-text search and use that for queries instead. It could be `FULLTEXT` key that MySQL natively supports in MyISAM tables, or an external full-text search engine such as Sphinx (http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) for example.

One you denormalize this into a single structure, you will be able to do all your queries very easily.

This does not mean you should get rid of your base structures, but rather in order to build an efficient solution for such searches, you will have to introduce some data duplication.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Union Select and combine your results . just use union with same selected columns in previous select :

```
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';


    $sWhere .= ' UNION SELECT question FROM questions , sections WHERE ( sections.`section` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' AND questions.section = sections.id ) "; //this union in select columns count  must be same with your previous Select columns count 

}
```